# Printing values in multiple arrays coming out a jarbled mess

Tags: python, regex, json, printing, newline

The values in the arrays are fine. If I print them out separately in a loop they come out as they should, but the moment I put them all together it doesn't print the first two values and jumbles the rest. Here's the print snippet:

```
print '['
for i in range(1, x):
    print '{\"' + fNames[0] + '\":"' + fNames[i] + '\", \"' + lNames[0] + '\":\"' + lNames[i] + '\", \"' + descs[0] + '\":\"' + descs[i] + '\"},\r'
print ']'
```

Here's what it outputs:

```
[
"},A really cool guy, "lname":"Bishop", "description
"},A really cool galname":"Patzer", "description
"},A really cool momlname":"Robertson", "description
"},A really cool dadame":"Bishop", "description
"},A really cool doglname":"Bishop", "description
"},A really cool cat"lname":"Jack", "description
]
```

Notice that it doesn't output fName[0] and fName[i].

If I comment out the end of the print statement like so:

```
print '['
for i in range(1, x):
    print '{\"' + fNames[0] + '\":"' + fNames[i] + '\", \"' + lNames[0] + '\":\"' + lNames[i] + '\", \"' + descs[0] + '\":\"' #+ descs[i] + '\"},'
print ']'
```

It prints out most of it correctly, besides the 'f' in "fname" and notice that it doesn't print out the last '\":\"' at all either. I've already ran the arrays through the filter() function to strip newlines, and made sure my regex doesn't pick them up. This is how I fill the arrays:

```
with open(file, "rb") as fin:
    for line in fin:
        col1Reg = re.search('^(.+?)(?=,)', line)
        fNames.append(col1Reg.group(0))

        col2Parsed = '(?<=' + fNames[x] + ',)(.*)(?=,)'
        col2Reg = re.search(col2Parsed, line)
        lNames.append(col2Reg.group(0))

        col3Parsed = '(?<=' + lNames[x] + ',)(.*)(?=\n)'
        col3Reg = re.search(col3Parsed, line)
        descs.append(col3Reg.group(0))

        x += 1
```

What the heck is going on? Everything in the arrays is correct and in the correct position, so why is this happening?

Comment: +1 for "jarbled mess"

Comment: In all seriousness, though, it's a good question.

Comment: Can you pprint the arrays? My blind guess is there are quotes in the inputs that are messing things up

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are trying to output json. Instead of building a string, why not create a list of dictionaries and dump it to json via something like this:

```
import json
list1 = []
for x in range(i):
  list1.append({
     'name': 'value',
  })
print json.dumps(list1, indent=4)
```